# Need assistance translating a few itinerary words from English to Japanese

Tags: translation

I'm traveling from the USA to Japan soon and I'd like to print out a big itinerary to put in my checked-in luggage just incase the luggage doesn't end up taking the same trip as me.

I just need a few words:

- Name (followed by my full name)
- Email address
- Mobile number
- Flight schedule (followed by my flight info - several legs)
- Hotel (followed by the hotel name, address, and phone number)

I tried looking at Google Translate and WordReference but I kept seeing very different translations so I have no confidence in what I was coming up with.

So far I have:

Name / 名前:
Mobile / 携帯電話:
Email / Eメール:
Flights / ??:
Hotel: ホテル:

I'd appreciate corrections for the 4 I have and an answer for "flights" (flight schedule). I don't know any Japanese so I have no idea if my attempts are even close.

Comment: @mlc I was torn between this site and that one. If it gets closed here then I will try there.

Comment: By the time someone opens your luggage, it's already been declared lost for good. Funny story: https://au.news.yahoo.com/couple-furious-after-airline-donates-lost-luggage-to-charity-criminal-053454579.html

Comment: @Hilmar - interesting story. I actually just bought a set of AirTags for this trip. Hopefully they won't be needed.

Comment: [Translations are off-topic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628) for Japanese Language Stack Exchange.  But I won't vote to close it in case you are able to migrate it somewhere else.

Comment: @istrasci I originally posted this question on the Travel site and someone there migrated it to this site. Seems like I can't win.

Comment: I guess they migrated it without checking our site Help Center.  Sorry I don't have any better recommendation for you... 

Comment: @istrasci Feel free to vote to close if appropriate. If I later find a better place to post it then I can repost it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**This is not necessary**, because if your bag gets lost, nobody is going to open it up.

- The baggage handling staff at the airport can figure out from the tag where it's supposed to go, who it belongs to, and how to contact you.
- More importantly, when you arrive at your destination and your bag doesn't show up, the first thing you need to do before you even leave the collection area is **make a lost luggage report**.  At this point you can talk to the staff right then and there and make sure they have your contact details, agree on where it should be delivered etc.  And yes, at any major Japanese airport, there will be English-speaking staff available.

Comment: (+1) Might be useful to have the hotel details ready in Japanese if the OP is planning on taking a taxi from the airport?

Comment: OK, this is a reasonable answer from when the question (and this answer) was posted on the travel site. Now that it's been migrated to the Japanese language site, this answer seems out of place. I'm going to wait to see if I get some actual translations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Flight" might be translated by フライトナンバー which is just flight number.